# Use custom html tag to display image on page

Tags: html

I am trying to use custom html tags (ideally within the Summernote HTML editor) to display an image. Custom tags are new to me and the examples I have seen don't seem to help me).

Essentially I want the user to add an html marker (within the html editor) which is replaced by an image eg.

`'<bell></bell>'` would display a custom image of a bell

Am I right in following the concept of custom HTML tags and can anyone help with a basic example?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:custom-tags]. Have you read what that tag means? Are you really asking how to allow users to supply you with Java libraries to execute on your server?

Comment: Hi Quentin - thank you ever so for taking the time to clarify.  No, that is not what I am asking.  In this context I am, hopefully, referring to HTML tags as per my example.

Comment: ...ah I now see my example is not showing - apologies - let me tidy the question.

Comment: [`Custom Elements`](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) <- This might make things easy for you.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you - tag removed as per your request.

Comment: @thebrownkid - I stumbled across a part of that site earlier but didnt see how it helped - you may have very kindly provided something interesting there - thank you so much.  Reading and digesting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is pretty forgiving and will let you create your own elements...

However, you will also have to create your own CSS rules to match them as well.

You will also need to build up any and all behaviors you would like for the element to have (in consideration for things like JavaScript, clicks, bubbling, ... ) It looks like the [Custom Element](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) site touches on how you can make these connections.

```css
bell{
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/golden-bell_1262-6415.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<bell></bell>
```

However, I would caution that using a custom element this way, may hurt a site's accessibility (image without alt text).

My takeaway/recommendation is feel free to use this for anything that is non-critical.  But if the element is something that will be need to be read/seen or interacted with, its probably best to go with the original elements designed for those purposes.